# chrome- print without dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a screen with a note printer which I want the user to be able to print automatically without needing to confirm. 
How can I print through Java Script or JQuery in Chrome without opening the printing dialog box?

Answer (score -1):

I think on click button, you just call window.print() function.

```
<a href='#' id='PrintPage' onclick='window.print();'> Click Here For Printing</a>
```

I hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: this brings up the print dialog.